# Using Jquery .toggle() to open a dropdown menu, need the link to change color when clicked

Tags: jquery, toggle, slide

I'm using the following code to cause a ul based dropdown menu to open, I have the css set up so that the 'button' changes color when you hover, but I need it to stay that color while the menu is open.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {

$('#nav li').toggle(
    function () {
        //show its submenu
        $('ul', this).slideDown(100);
        $('#libg').toggleClass('clicked');
    },
    function () {
        //hide its submenu
        $('ul', this).slideUp(100);
        $('#libg').toggleClass('notclicked');
    }
);
});
</script>
```

There aren't any errors in firebug, the slide events work perfectly fine, maybe I'm not calling the right thing? #libg is the id of the li that contains the 'button'. The clicked / notclicked classes only change the background-color.

http://jsfiddle.net/5tV45/

Comment: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net), please?

Comment: Showing the HTML would be useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I expect you want to toggle the `clicked` class both times, so when it is removed, it is in the state of `notclicked`

```
    // replace this...
    // $('#libg').toggleClass('notclicked');
    // with this...
    $('#libg').toggleClass('clicked');
```

Comment: This, and the above post, didn't seem to do anything. I've posted the jsfiddle in a comment of the original post if it helps.

Comment: The javascript works, the style rule is not specific enough, and is being overwritten. Try: `li#libg.clicked li a { color: #fff; background-color: #839367; }
` which will act on the anchors within the list items within the clicked items with id libg.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, if I put that line in the css, it makes a good portion of the dropdown change color, which I don't want.

Comment: Used #libg.clicked { color: #fff; background-color: #839367; }

Comment: Glad you got what you wanted ,~)

Answer (score 0):

You just need to specify color in your 'clicked' class and toggle it in both functions:

```
$('#nav li').toggle(
    function () {
        //show its submenu
        $('ul', this).slideDown(100);
        $('#libg').toggleClass('clicked');
    },
    function () {
        //hide its submenu
        $('ul', this).slideUp(100);
        $('#libg').toggleClass('clicked');
    }
);
```

In your version 'clicked' class left on the menu item when you closing menu.

Comment: Didn't make it any different unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

Could you just set the colour in the function?

```
$(this).css({color: '#f00'});
```

... to set the colour, and...

```
$(this).css({color: ''});
```

... to unset it. Though you might be better using add/removeClass